# Function pointer - read math function names and arguments on the command line in C

Tags: c

I am self-teaching c and came across one of the problem. Following is a simplified form of a problem statement but can be good hint for me.

I have a structure that hold information about type of trigonometric function it is, the function address itself and number of required arguments as defined below,

```
struct math
   {
      char *name;                      // name of math function
      double (*pmf)();                 // pointer to math function
      int nargs;                       // number of arguments
   };
```

All I am trying to read a type of function on command line and call matching function the function. The entire code is as listed below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARGS 3
#define elements(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof((array)[0]))

struct math
   {
      char *name;                      // name of math function
      double (*pmf)();                 // pointer to math function
      int nargs;                       // number of arguments
   };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   static struct math table = {"cos", cos, 1};
/*
   static struct math table[] =
   {
      {"acos", acos, 1},
      {"asin", asin, 1},
      {"atan", atan, 1},
      {"sqrt", sqrt, 1},
      {"cos", cos, 1},
      {"cosh", cosh, 1},
      {"sin", sin, 1},
      {"sinh", sinh, 1},
      {"tan", tan, 1},
      {"tanh", tanh, 1},
      {"exp", exp, 1},
      {"log", log, 1},
      //{"pow", pow, 2},
      {"log10", log10, 1},

   };
 */
   // command line argument must be atleast 3
   if (argc < ARGS)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "<usage: %s arg1 [arg 2]\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
   }

   double arg1 = atof(argv[2]);
   //char *ptr;
   //ptr = argv[1];

   // parse through all the maths function for a input match
   // if there is amatch then execute the function call

   //if(table.name == *ptr)
   if(table.name == argv[2])
   {
      //table.pmf = table.pmf;
      printf("%f\n", (*table.pmf)(arg1));
   }

/*
   for(int fnctNumber = 0; fnctNumber < elements(table); fnctNumber++)
   {
      if (strcmp(argv[1], table->name))
      {
         //table.name =
         printf("%f\n", (table->pmf)[fnctNumber](arg1));
      }
   }
*/
   return 0;
}
```

Would anybody through light on it? What I am missing...

Comment: What is your specific problem? There is no question here.  please clarify

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] question to clarify what errors/unexpected behavior you see. It looks like commented out code is actually what you want... but obviously it is not going to run when it is commented out...

Comment: You define the function pointer to take 0 arguments `double (*pmf)(); ` and then try to point it to `cos` which does NOT take 0 arguments.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That doesn't specify how many arguments. `double (*pmf)(void)` means 0 arguments.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah This is C, not C++.

Comment: Why did you comment out the array and the looping code? That's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Ok, if you don't need to specify the exact function pointer signature in C then this works: https://onlinegdb.com/BkB0sdNXu  I thought maybe you did need a different function pointer signature for each function like you do in C++ - which means using a union like https://onlinegdb.com/S1fPnuNm_

Comment: You are not using `nargs` anywhere, and you have commented out `pow`. Coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers... I was able to fix the code as follows. Have a critical look at it!

```
// calc.c
// a program reads math function names and arguments on the
// command line

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARGS 3
#define elements(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof((array)[0]))

struct math
   {
      char *name;                      // name of math function
      double (*pmf)();                 // pointer to math function
      int nargs;                       // number of arguments
   };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   //static struct math table = {"cos", cos, 1};
   
   static struct math table[] =
   {
      {"acos", acos, 1},
      {"asin", asin, 1},
      {"atan", atan, 1},
      {"sqrt", sqrt, 1},
      {"cos", cos, 1},
      {"cosh", cosh, 1},
      {"sin", sin, 1},
      {"sinh", sinh, 1},
      {"tan", tan, 1},
      {"tanh", tanh, 1},
      {"exp", exp, 1},
      {"log", log, 1},
      //{"pow", pow, 2},
      {"log10", log10, 1},

   };

   // command line argument must be atleast 3
   if (argc < ARGS)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "<usage: %s arg1 [arg 2]\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
   }
   //printf("argv[1] = %s\n", argv[1]);
   double arg1 = atof(argv[2]);

   for(int fnctNumber = 0; fnctNumber < (int)elements(table); fnctNumber++)
   {
      // This comparsion fails at log10 and log ***CHECK***
      //if (*table[fnctNumber].name == *argv[1])
      //   printf("%s = %f\n",table[fnctNumber].name, (*table[fnctNumber].pmf)(arg1));
         
      if (!strcmp(table[fnctNumber].name, argv[1]))
         printf("%s = %f\n",table[fnctNumber].name, (*table[fnctNumber].pmf)(arg1));
   }

   return 0;
}
```